# General error: 3988 Conversion from collation utf8_unicode_ci into utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci impossible for parameter

Tags: mysql, laravel, collation, utf8mb4

I'm trying to save a string containing html of an email in a text type column. but i'm getting this error. I failed finding where's the incompatible caractere. There is any sanitizing method that i can use to convert all `utf8_unicode_ci` into `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci`?

Comment: Please locate the "incompatible character" and show us the hex of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My specific problem was actually caused by PHP [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).

```php
echo substr('ããããã', 0, 5);
//ãã�
```

It use [utf8_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php), get the substring and then use [utf8_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php). In this example the string "ããããã" becomes "Ã£Ã£Ã£Ã£Ã£" after the internal call to utf8_encode, then is cropped to "Ã£Ã£Ã" by substr, and when utf8_encode is aplied it endup with "ãã�".

I solved this using the [Laravel helper substr](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-str-substr) instead of the php one.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the text before inserting to the right collation

```
SELECT CONVERT('abc' USING utf8mb4)  COLLATE  utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```